# Unable to drag & drop icons & links from firefox (I'm New)

Tags: firefox, desktop-icons, drag-and-drop, url

Hi so I recently switched over to Ubuntu and one things that I dislike is that I'm unable to drag & drop icons & links from firefox to my desktop.

I checked under permissions and I have full permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a new profile. Follow FF's steps [here:](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles)

Comment: I’m sure it has nothing to do with my Firefox profile as I have installed Ubuntu many times.

Answer (score 0):

This works differently in Ubuntu to what you might have been used to in the Windows desktop environment.

Generally, to save links from Firefox and to access them later within Firefox it is possible to drag and drop them to a Bookmarks sidebar. See [this](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/12/15/manage-firefox-tabs-bookmarks-and-containers-in-the-sidebar/) reference.
The advantage of this is to keep the desktop relatively uncluttered.

It has a further advantage that if you set up your profile in a Firefox account, you can synchronise your settings across other devices.

However, there is still an option to drag and drop between desktop and file browser using the GNOME Extension Desktop Icons NG

[image]

See [this reference](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/10/enable-drag-drop-desktop-ubuntu-20-04/) as to how to enable it.